# im trying to find biggest negative number in array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, negative-number

Running perfect but there is no result only cursor. The expected result is `-15`

```
        int[] dizi = { 4, 5, -15, 22, -34, 3, 0, 7, 43, 100 };
        int maxNumber = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dizi.Length; i++)
        {
            if (dizi[i] < 0)
            {
                if (maxNumber < dizi[i])
                {
                    maxNumber = dizi[i];
                    Console.WriteLine(maxNumber);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: If there is no result, how is it running perfectly?

Comment: `if (maxNumber < dizi[i])` If maxNumber is 0, it will never be smaller than a negative number.

Comment: Use a debugger. Go through it line by line. You'll notice what @Dennis_E said to be the problem.

Comment: it should be `if (maxNumber > dizi[i])`

Comment: I Second what Sami says: If you want to really learn what is wrong with it, single-step through it in the debugger. There's no better way to understand your code.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Where` and `Max` extension methods from `System.Linq` namespace:

```
var maxNegative = dizi.Where(x => x < 0).Max(); 
Console.WriteLine(maxNegative);
```

`Max()` will throw exception if there is not any negative number in the collection. So, you may want to use `DefaultIfEmpty` if you want to return `0` instead of any exception:

```
var maxNegative = dizi.Where(x => x < 0)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .Max();
```

Comment: @AnektarcıLegend Actually, this is not a big deal. But, of course it might be  better to write your own code in the beginning rather than using Linq methods

Comment: +1 for `.DefaultIfEmpty()` mentioning. Extreme cases (no negative numbers in this particular code) are worth considering.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Max()` to determine your desired value

```
int[] dizi = { 4, 5, -15, 22, -34, 3, 0, 7, 43, 100 };
int result = dizi.Where(x => x < 0).Max();
```

---

If you want to keep your code, replace `int maxNumber = 0;` with `int maxNumber = int.MinValue;` so `maxNumber` gets overwritten, otherwise there can't be a bigger negative number compared to `0`

Comment: the question is vague defined so i assume there are negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int maxNumber = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dizi.length; i++) {
        if (dizi[i] < 0) {
            if (maxNumber == 0 || dizi[i] > maxNumber ) {
                maxNumber = dizi[i];
            }
        }
    }
return maxNumber;
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/gqA0FY)**

Comment: thx @Rahul Tripathi once i add 'maxNumber == 0 ||' i get right result

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for *non-Linq* solution (good old loop):

```
    int[] dizi = { 4, 5, -15, 22, -34, 3, 0, 7, 43, 100 };
    int maxNumber = 0;

    foreach (var item in dizi)
      if ((item < 0) && (maxNumber == 0 || item > maxNumber))
        maxNumber = item;

    Console.WriteLine(maxNumber);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

This code either prints out the maximum negative number `-15` or `0` if the coolection (`dizi`) doesn't contain any negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

i realize if maxNumber lower than any array elements for example `int maxNumber=-100` program works too

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this and you will get the correct output

```
   max=0;
   while(i<dizi.Length)
   {
      if(dizi[i]<max)
       max=dizi[i];
      i++;
   }
   if(max!=0)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(max);
   }
   else Console.WriteLine("No negative number")
 }
```